# Appropriate location of the .git file, directory arrangement and question about `REMOTE URL`

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-remote

[image: My folder arrangement]

I have a folder on my Desktop called GitHub. In this GitHub folder are all my repositories which I would like to host on my GitHub remote page (sorry if I get the terminology wrong, by remote page I mean, I want to see each of these folders as a repository on my https://www.github.com/abhishekbabuji page.

Now everything was fine, I followed an online tutorial... But I think I really messed up somewhere.

My questions are the following:

1. Should there be a `.git`. inside every single one of the folders/repository? or should there be JUST ONE `.git` file in this main folder of mine like in the picture and NO `.git` inside ANY of the folders? I'm given to understand that `.git` is used to TRACK the changes you make, and you need **not** have one inside every repo.
2. Before I push, it looks like I have to set up a remote url as `git remote add origin <REMOTE URL>` where the `<REMOTE URL>` is a PATH TO ONE REPO.

But this is where I'm having the most trouble.. If the `<REMOTE URL>` is a PATH TO ONE SPECIFIC REPO, wouldn't that mean that every time I make changes, ALL the changes that I make inside these 6 folders you see in the image GO INSIDE THAT SINGLE REPO, instead of there being 6 separate REPOS?

How do I add a `<REMOTE URL>` ensuring that all the changes go into their 6 respective repos when I do `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push` from the current directory `GitHub`? I'm willing to make whatever changes I need to ensure I get this right, changes in directory arrangement, changes in `.git` location, anything. I just want to make sure that there are 6 separate repos on my GitHub page (It currently exists as of now, but I don't know what happened, when I tried doing `git push`, it started to say that the repo destination does not exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From git's perspective, there's no relationship between these six folders. Each one should have its own `.git` folder, and for each one you should run `git remote add origin <url>` separately.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the clarification. I was afraid my question will be intelligible. Does this also mean that I must remove the `.git` from the MAIN folder `GitHub` and add them only to the individual 6 local folders?

Comment: @Abhishek It's not just about creating a `.git` folder. You need to actually initialize the git repos there. Unless you've cloned them from GitHub (in which case they should already have `.git` folders), you could run `git init` in each of them.

Comment: So I run `git init` on all 6 folders. I understand that, do I need to remove the `.git` which is present in the `GitHub` folder? aka (Main directory that has 6 local subdirectories, each with its own `.git` folder. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Abhishek I don't think having that folder will cause any harm, but you might as well remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this question. Rarely get you 179k folks to reply to noob questions.